# passenger での設定値の確認方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

apache + passenger を使っています。

```
$ passenger-config about version
4.0.58
```

例えば [PassengerPoolIdleTime](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerpoolidletime) の値をセットしたのですが、確認する方法はありますでしょうか？

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /home/app/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.58
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/app/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby
  PassengerPoolIdleTime 1200
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

PassengerPoolIdleTimeは、設定したアイドル時間を超えたらプロセスが殺される設定ですが、PassengerMinInstancesという設定もあります。これは、最低限維持するプロセス数を指定する設定なのですが、デフォルトでは1となります。

したがって、PassengerMinInstancesを0にして、PassengerPoolIdleTimeで設定した秒数待機すれば、プロセスがkillされるのではないかと思います。